# Is there a good word to describe the things that are done to make the world a better place?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, vocabulary

Basically I'm looking for an umbrella term that would include fields of work like curing diseases, generating clean energy, getting access to clean water, etc.

For context, there will be a line in my resume about what kind of companies/projects I'm interested in.

The closest I've come up with is *social good* but it seems slightly off.

Any suggestions?

Comment: An example sentence would be helpful.

Comment: How about *social responsibility*?

Answer (score 1):

An appropriate term would be **altruistic**.

> unselfish regard for or devotion to the welfare of others

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/altruism

Answer (score 0):

In Hebrew you could use "Mitzva" but that only translates to commandment in English. I think a word you could use is "service" or many use "good deed". I hope this helps!

Comment: Answers as well as questions should be in and about the english language.

Comment: @vickyace "Mitzvah" is fairly well-understood (and used) in the US.

Comment: @vickyace Many Yiddish words are to found in the lexicon of the English language and have found their way into such thoroughly kosher dictionaries as the Oxford series and Merriam-Webster. So, I shall now keep shtum, schlep over to my local bagel shop and have a good nosh! Enjoy! Oy vey! I have just discovered that Mr, Vickyace is a skilled martial artist and boxer